# Bug while tracing wifi supplicant implementation from JNI in Android 4.2

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-wifi, android-source

I am debugging through Android 4.2 Sources to find out a problem in WiFi Direct. While going through the native implementation WifiNative.java in androiid.net.wifi package, I found that the first level native functions has been implemented in android_net_wifi_Wifi.cpp. But not able to understand how the flow is going to down to driver level. For example,

```
static jboolean android_net_wifi_startSupplicant(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jboolean p2pSupported)
{
    return (jboolean)(::wifi_start_supplicant(p2pSupported) == 0);
}
```

Where is wifi_start_supplicant(p2pSupported) method implemented? What is the meaning of :: symbol here, i.e. to which class this method is a member?

Answer (score 1):

wifi_start_supplicant() is implemented at libhardware_legacy, which is usually located at /hardware/libhardware_legacy\